# NextJS (Production): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'segment')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, next.js, frontend

Recently deployed my web application client (front end only) in a nextjs build on digital ocean. My web application is able to run on dev without these unhandled errors and I'm not able to get a verbose enough stack trace to debug this any further. Trial and error has yielded no success.

How can I get more verbose logs in prod?

The error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'segment') at S (/home/app/.next/server/chunks/2395.js:1:25932) at nT (/home/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46138) at nT (/home/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:59937) at nO (/home/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:62795) at nT (/home/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:59556) at nO (/home/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:62795) at nR (/home/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:45694) at nT (/home/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46289) at nT (/home/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:59937) at nO (/home/app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:62795)`

Occurs between any route and the redirection to the dashboard (aka login, onboarding). The weird part is if you manually navigate to dashboard/settings, you are able to then navigate backwards to the dashboard and the data is all correct. This suggests to me it's something like accessing a property that is null on initial render.

`'use server'

import { Goals_FetchAll_ApiResponseSchema } from "@/lib/responsemodels/goals/fetchAll";
import { User_Me_ResponseSchema } from "@/lib/responsemodels/user/me"
import { revalidatePath } from "next/cache";

import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

export async function getDashbardInitData() {
try {
const apiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL || 'https://localhost:5002/api/v1';
const token = cookies().get('token');
const res =  await fetch(`${apiUrl}/user/me`, {
method: 'GET',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
Cookie: `token=${token?.value}`,
},
cache: 'no-cache',
credentials: 'include',
})

```
  const apiData = await res.json();

  if (!res?.ok) {
    if(res?.status === 403) {
      redirect('/expiredsession');
    }
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    console.log(res?.statusText)
    throw new Error('Api Error')
  }

  const validation = User_Me_ResponseSchema.safeParse(apiData);

  if (!validation?.success) {
      console.log(validation?.error)
      throw new Error('validation error');   
  } else {
      revalidatePath('/dashboard')
     return validation?.data
  }
} catch (error: any) {
  console.log(`Error is occuring: ${error}`);
  throw new Error('Error during Dashboard fetch');   
}
```

}

export async function getGoalData(userId: string) {
try {
const apiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL || 'https://localhost:5002/api/v1';

```
  const token = cookies().get('token');
  const res =  await fetch(`${apiUrl}/goals/fetchAll/${userId}`, {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Cookie: `token=${token?.value}`,
  },
  cache: 'no-cache',
  credentials: 'include',
});

  const apiData = await res.json()
     
  if (!res?.ok) {
    if(res?.status === 403) {
      redirect('/expiredsession');
    }
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    console.log(res?.statusText)
    throw new Error('Api Error')
   
  }

  const validation = Goals_FetchAll_ApiResponseSchema.safeParse(apiData);

  if (!validation?.success) {
      console.log(validation?.error)
      throw new Error('validation error');   
  } else {
      revalidatePath('/dashboard')
     return validation?.data
  }
} catch (error: any) {
  console.log(`Error is occuring: ${error}`);
  throw new Error('Error during Dashboard fetch');   
}
```

}
`

Attempted to reproduce in dev, unable to because the app runs normally. Tried to repro this in build -> prod locally and don't run into the error either. Tried catching with error boundaries, no luck.